# I want to train a open source LLM model on my custom dataset [don't want to use openai]

Tags: chatgpt-api, langchain, llama-index

I am trying to use a open source LLM model ggml-gpt4all-l13b-snoozy.bin (it is downloaded from https://gpt4all.io/index.html).

I want to use the same model embeddings and create a ques answering chat bot for my custom data (using the lanchain and llama_index library to create the vector store and reading the documents from dir)

below is the code

```
from llama_cpp import Llama
from langchain.embeddings import LlamaCppEmbeddings
from llama_index import (
    GPTVectorStoreIndex,
    SimpleDirectoryReader, 
    LLMPredictor,
    PromptHelper,
    ServiceContext,
    LangchainEmbedding
)

llama_embeddings = LlamaCppEmbeddings(model_path=model_path))
### checking if embeddings are generated using custom model
llama_embeddings.embed_query("this is a test document")

llm = LlamaCpp(
    model_path=model_path, verbose=True, n_ctx=2048
)


# reading a directory with pdf files 
loader = DirectoryLoader('pdf')
documents = loader.load()
text_splitter = CharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=1000)
texts = text_splitter.split_documents(documents)


# storing the embeddings in chroma db 
db = Chroma.from_documents(texts, llama_embeddings)
retriever = db.as_retriever()
# and then using the RetrievalQA to query the documents 

from langchain.chains import RetrievalQA
qa = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(llm=llm, chain_type="stuff", retriever=retriever)
query = "who is the author of the poem"
qa.run(query)
```

But it is not returning the results
I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: `retriever=retriever` does what in your code? I mean, `db` has to be converted to `retriever`, if not it would be `None`

Comment: I missed out that line 
retriever = db.as_retriever() 
I have updated the code snippet also